# How is the maxbyte property supposed to work?

Tags: jms, tibco, tibco-ems

according the [documentation tor TIBCO EMS](https://docs.tibco.com/pub//ems_client_for_zos_mvs/6.0.0-july-2010/docs/tib_ems_users_guide.pdf)

*"For queues, **maxbytes** defines the maximum size (in bytes) that the queue can
store, summed over all messages in the queue. **Should this limit be exceeded,
messages will be rejected by the server** and the message producer send calls will
return an error."*

Currently one of our queues have **maxbytes** set to **500000000** but the pending msgs size is much higher, **2.5GB**

How can this be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that the `maxbytes` property only pertains to **undelivered** pending messages. It means that messages that have been delivered but not yet acknowledged by the JMS consumer(s) are not taken into account in the calculation of the `maxbytes` property.

When you issue `show queue <queue_name>` with the EMS administration tool, does the `Delivered Msgs` value seem particularly high?

Answer (score 1):

What Nicolas Heitz is saying seems to be correct.

I ran a simple test locally to reproduce this, using TIBCO Designer to send and receive large messages with approx 4Mb size and a queue configured with maxbytes set to 100Kb,

This is what the queue looked like before the test started:
[image]

### First scenario, no receivers on the queue.

It was possible to send one 4MB message to the queue, but any message after this fails.

[image]

### Second scenario, one receiver not acknowledging messages

Starting point, one 4MB pending message on the queue

Sending a second message works
[image]

It appears to be possible to keep sending messages, as long as there is an active receiver on the queue processing messages without having acknowledged them yet.

[image]

### Conclusion

In case of a slow consumer not acknowledging the messages it receives fast enough, **maxbytes** will not limit the **pending msgs size** on a queue.

If there is no consumer on the queue, then **maxbytes** will be checked before a message is sent, and if the limit is reached, the message producer will receive an error from the ems server an no new messages can be sent.

The **maxbytes** property is not blocking a message larger than **maxbytes** from being sent to the queue.